# Displaying elements side-by-side using Flexbox and vertically align their content not working

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I have implemented the following menu using Flexbox:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: '';
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5DA0E8;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav .header {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  padding-left: 20px;
}

nav .searchbar {
  background-color: #4170A3;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
  vertical-align: super;
  color: white;
  width: 250px;
  font-family: 'Dosis';
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#search-icon {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  vertical-align: super;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: #4170A3;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav .flex-display {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span class="header">PLANS DU BAC</span>
  
  <div class="flex-display">
    <input type="search" name="" value="" class="searchbar" />
    <img src="./ressources/media/search-icon.svg" alt="" id="search-icon" />
  </div>
</nav>
```

I'd like the title and the search box to be side-by-side, but somehow the `display: flex` thing kicks the search bar out of the `<div>`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't try to game the question quality filters. There are reasons why they're in place.

Comment: Try adding "flex" property to the nav elements children's css rules.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the title (`.header`) and the wrapper of the search input (`.flex-display`) to be side by side, you need to set `display: flex` on the parent element (`.header`) and then play with the `flex` property to expand or shrink them as you wish.

Probably this is closer to what you are trying to achieve. Check the comments to know what the code is doing and hover over the menu to highlight the relevant elements in different colors:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}


/*
  We want the parent element to be a flex container so that both children
  (in cyan and yellow) take over all the horitzontal space.
*/
#navigation__base {
  display: flex;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}

/*
  We want this flex element to be able to shrink or grow and to take
  the remainig space (flex: 1 1 auto).
  
  At the same time, we want it to be a flex container so that the link
  inside it takes the exact space that it needs to fit the text.
*/
#navigation__title {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

/*
  We want this to be a flex container as well so that we can vertically
  center the text without changing the line-height, as that might look
  ugly with multiline texts.
  
  At the same time, we want it to be a flex container so that we can
  vertically center the text inside it easily and without using line-height,
  which doesn't work well with multiline text.
*/
#navigation__link {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

/*
  We want this flex element to be shrink to its minimum size to fit
  its contant and not grow to absorb any extra free space in the
  flex container (flex: 0 1 auto).
  
  At the same time, we want it to be a flex container so that we can
  easily vertically center the input inside it.
*/
#search__base {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
}

/*
  Nothin fancy after this.
*/
#search__input {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 10px;
  color: #000;
  width: 250px;
  transition: width ease-in 250ms;
}

#search__input:focus {
  outline: none;
  width: 450px;
}

#search__icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 24px;
  transform: translate(-9px, -9px);
}

/*
  Just so that you can see the space that each element is taking.
*/
#navigation__base:hover > #navigation__title { background: cyan; }
#navigation__base:hover > #search__base { background: yellow; }
#navigation__base:hover #navigation__link { background: red; }
```

```html
<header id="navigation__base">
  <h1 id="navigation__title">
    <a id="navigation__link" href="#">PLANS DU BAC</a>
  </h1>
  
  <label id="search__base">
    <input id="search__input" type="search"  />
    <img id="search__icon" src="./ressources/media/search-icon.svg" alt="" />
  </label>
</header>
```